# Weird behaviour of date search with between query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two dates: **2017-01-10 02:00:00**

AND: **2017-01-10 00:00:00**

When I execute the query:

```
SELECT id
FROM users 
WHERE end_date
BETWEEN '2017-01-01'
AND '2017-01-10'
```

I get the second record, but not the first?

Why?

Comment: Wrong. It get the second record, not the first record. because the first date is not in your given range.

Comment: You're right. Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong. It get the second record, not the first record. because the first date is not in your given range.

You want to compare only the date part of the column using `date` function.

```
SELECT id
FROM users 
WHERE date(end_date) between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-10'
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working because `'2017-01-10'` is expanded to `2017-01-10 00:00:00`.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT id
FROM users 
WHERE end_date
BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND '2017-01-10 23:59:59'
```